# Windows 10 batch to run .msi

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

I'm fairly new to batch files, especially in the instance that I'm being asked to do so now.

We have a lot of older batch files on the network that run ".kix" files and they've worked great for years.  My company though, is moving to Windows 10 and a lot of these old batch files won't run because of Windows 10 enhanced security.

I've looked around and have found a remedy for this, but I have run into a snag.  I have a batch file that runs a ".msi" file.  The fix I had for the .kix files is:

```
Set "kixCommand=\\abc123\Scripts\KIX\kix32.exe"    *(abc123 is the network server name)*  
Set "kixFile=\\abc123\Scripts\Apps\My Program\MyProgram.kix"

:UACPrompt
   echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "C:\ICS_Tools\Temp\getadmin.vbs"  
   echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %kixCommand% %kixFile%", "", "runas", 1 >> "C:\ICS_Tools\Temp\getadmin.vbs"  
   "C:\ICS_Tools\Temp\getadmin.vbs"
   del "C:\ICS_Tools\Temp\getadmin.vbs"  
  exit /B
```

The batch creates a local vbs script, runs it supposedly with admin rights, then deletes it.

I tried to use the same method for the .msi file.  The .vbs file looks like this:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")   
UAC.ShellExecute "msiexec.exe /i \\abc123\Scripts\Apps\My Program2\setup.msi", "", "runas", 1
```

For some reason though, it says it cannot find the command (see attached picture).

[image: msi_error_pic]

I would really appreciate some expert help on this.  I've tried using quotes (because of the space in the folder name "My Program2"), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I notice that your supplied image of the error is (quite obviously) doctored, with parts of the text replaced entirely. Please don't do that (except to redact sensitive information). Our only "evidence" of your problem description is cast into doubt. It leaves us not knowing what to trust, and unsure of whether spending time on an answer will be worthwhile. Fortunately, in this case, the problem is clear anyway (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Your new code merges two arguments into the executable path. There is indeed no executable named `msiexec.exe /i \\abc123\Scripts\Apps\My Program2\setup.msi`, so the failure is expected.

Instead, try:

```
UAC.ShellExecute "msiexec.exe", "/i", "\\abc123\Scripts\Apps\My Program2\setup.msi", "", "runas", 1
```

Your original code (and the trailing parts of the new one) got this right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Yes I changed some info as I felt it was company private.  I did not mean to deceive anyone with my question.  If I do post again (and need to change anything) I'll explain that I did it for company privacy.  Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MarkGinAZ: Just black out the sensitive bits. Don't mock up a whole new replacement screenshot (which is effectively what you did!)

Comment: Ok, here's the actual vbs file:    Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "msiexec.exe", "/i", "\\asvfasp03\tools\Apps\Gerber Rename and Zip\setup.msi", "", "runas", 1 
When this gets run, it says "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment 'UAC.ShellExecute' (these are two separate lines, but the comment won't let me show that)

Comment: Ok, so no more ideas?  I've searched all over, but don't understand the problem.